# Javascript, moving elements in an array from front to back

Tags: javascript

I have an array that contains variables and functions. The array is 80 elements long. The first 20 elements are used together in a for loop. When the loop has completed, the first twenty elements are moved to the back of the array, and the for loop starts again.

I am rebuilding the array this way:

```
var a2=[the array with 80 elements];
run(a2);
function run(array){
  var n=array.slice(0,20); array.splice(0,20);
  var con=array.concat(n); a2=con;
  }
```

So I am basically indexing the (new) sliced array, re-indexing the (original) array after the splice, indexing a (new) array after the concat, and re-indexing the original again when I set it equal to the concat. This seems like it is too inefficient. Is there a more established approach to this?

Comment: You could chain a little more :-)

Comment: What is `a2`? An implicit global?

Comment: sorry about that. a2 =[the array]

Comment: Do you realise you are breaking encapsulation this way? You _assume_ the argument is `a2`. Either don't assume this, or enforce this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to `slice()` and then `splice()`. `Splice()` **returns** the removed elements, so you just need to do that:

```
var n = array.splice(0, 20);
a2 = array.concat(n);
```

---

To be completely clear, JavaScript's [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method returns **the removed elements**, not the remaining elements.

Also, using globals is generally a bad idea, but you are also kinda mixing them in a weird way. If you are going to keep the variable global, I would either pass the original in as a parameter and return the result from the function:

```
var a2=[the array with 80 elements];
a2 = run(a2);

function run(array){
    var n = array.splice(0, 20);
    return array.concat(n);
}
```

OR

don't pass it in at all and just reference the global from the get-go:

```
var a2=[the array with 80 elements];
run();

function run(){
    var n = a2.splice(0, 20);
    a2 = a2.concat(n);
}
```

Comment: so, `array = array.concat(array.splice(0, 20))`?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yes, those are the same. My way takes up one more line of code, yours is slightly more confusing. Tomato-Tomahto.

Comment: splice removes the first 20 and returns the remaining 60 elements. with your way I would be adding 60 elements to the array correct?

Comment: @WilliamSmith splice returns the values it removes. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: What I'm worried about is that `array` is a function argument. This means that there is potentially a reference to the 60-element remnant.

Comment: @WilliamSmith Update: now I'm worried that you assume that `run` will only ever be called as `run(a2)`.

Comment: Yes, I see. I was looking at the original array which shows the remaining 60. I didn't realize that a new array was created with the removed. Big help. Thanks!!

Comment: was using those names as a quick test. arbitrary. not what I'm using in my real code. I guess that was misleading and a bad idea. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You wanted efficiency, so here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Hvcbj/

```
//This is tightly coupled to work for the first 20 of an 80 length array
function swapTwenty( array )
{
 for( var i = 0, max = 20; i < max; i++ )
 {
  var temp = array[i];
  for( var n = 1, len = 4; n < len; n++)
  {
   var base = (i + 20 * (n - 1)) % 80;
   var tar = (i + 20 * n) % 80;
   array[base] = array[tar];
   array[tar] = temp;
  }
 }
}
```

**EDIT**

I had assumed that by swapping in place instead of creating more arrays time would be saved, but in fact I do not think it is. Although this may have a smaller footprint on memory, it does not run faster than the accepted answer. Here is a jsperf showing the difference: http://jsperf.com/array-modifications

Comment: that's awesome answer! I was really wondering if your solution would actually be faster. thanks for the followup.